# Is it possible to export rules from the URL Rewrite module in IIS 7.5?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I see there's an **Import Rules** link in the feature's page, but is there a way to export the rules?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found that the rules are all written to Web.Config. So I just copied them to the new machine from there.

IIS Manager loads the rules from Web.Config, so it's all pretty clean.